# How to wrap long lines in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

I've setup a `colorcolumn=80`, but I found I can not wrap long lines in ~/.vimrc.

Is there any method like C's `\` to concatenate?

For example I tried this, but it does not work.

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal ai si et sta sw=4 \
textwidth=80 backspace=indent,eol,start fo=croql
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Lines in the `.vimrc` file can be wrapped by putting the escaping `\` at the **beginning** of the continuation line:

```
autocmd FileType python
    \ setlocal ai si et sta sw=4
    \ textwidth=80 backspace=indent,eol,start fo=croql
```

See `:h line-continuation`

Comment: tks, where to find the document, I can not find it.  I've tried `:help vimrc`

Comment: Agreed, I couldn't find this in the documentation, although I'm sure it's there somewhere.  I found it by examining .vimrc files until I found it.

Comment: See `:help line-continuation` for description of the line continuation syntax in Vim scripts.

Comment: I haven't managed to comment continued line - seems all the following line continuations are considered as comment.
Is there any solution?