# How do I split long lines in a .vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I've got a line in my `.vimrc` that is more than 80 chars long:

```
autocmd FileType python set smartindent cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with
```

I find this rather annoying, so I want to break it into multiple lines, but I don't know how to do that. I tried `\` since that does the trick in Python and the Bourne shell, but apparently that's not valid syntax in Vim:

```
autocmd FileType python set smartindent \
    cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with
```

gives

```
E492: Not an editor command
```

Can anyone tell me how to split this line?

(Bonus points if someone can tell me how to add to `cinwords` instead of resetting it entirely; the only thing I wanted to achieve is add the `with` keyword to it.)

Comment: Close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006117/wrap-long-lines-in-vimrc.

Comment: @CodeGnome: didn't search for line wrapping because I thought that meant something else, but you're right.

Comment: If you are doing some filetype-specific things you should be using `:setlocal`, not `:set`. The command you posted adds `with` to the 'cinwords' and sets 'smartindent' in every subsequent buffer, not only python, unless this buffer filetype plugin overrides it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
autocmd FileType python set smartindent
    \ cinwords+=with
```

Answer (score 66):

Hit `:help line-continuation`.

Basically you have to add `\` at the beginning of the continued line.

So instead of writing

```
autocmd FileType python set smartindent \
    cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with
```

you have to write

```
autocmd FileType python set smartindent
       \ cinwords=if,elif,else,for,while,try,except,finally,def,class,with
```

Comment: Yeah, for the sake of making your question helpful to others, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @shime Can we also separate `cinwords=if...` line using \ as in `if, \elif...`?